# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ifconfig'

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I were taught how to change mac address by 2 methods of `subprocess.call` while the first one was successful but the second method is giving me error and I am unable to understand it
this is my code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3.5
import subprocess
interface = input("Enter Interface of Your Choice: ")
mac_chg = input("Enter New Mac Address: ")
print("[+]Changing Mac ADDRESS of " + interface + " to " + mac_chg)
subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "down"])
subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "hw", "ether", mac_chg])
subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "up"])
```

this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/PycharmProjects/hello/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "down"])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 340, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ifconfig'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am unable to progress because of this error.

Comment: Be sure about the right  given interface and also permission for run the ifconfig command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In linux by default the `subprocess.call` doesn't use a shell to run our commands so you can't use the shell commands like `cd`.

so just add one more parameter to `subprocess.call` i.e `shell=True` and then try to execute.

For ex:

```py
subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "down"], shell=True)
```

Comment: You're right about `cd` because it's a shell builtin. But `ifconfig` is not a shell builtin in Bash. It's an executable and subprocess module can find and run it. I can easily call `subprocess.call(["ifconfig"])` without passing `shell=True`.